# What's the best way to pipeline assets to a CDN with Django?

Tags: python, django, deployment, cdn

When it comes time to deploy, one best practice is compressing static assets (js, css), and moving them to a CDN. There are a few Django apps that handle some aspects (`django-compressor`, `django-pipeline` each come to mind), but they each have their own problems. For example,

- `django-compressor` wants to generate content inside of the request/response loop, even when exclusively-offline compression is enabled.
- `django-pipeline` doesn't store hashes anywhere, so it iterates through the path it writes compressed files to, regex-matches filenames, sorts those *possible* matches, and returns the last item in the list. Try doing this from a CDN! What?!

The (seemingly logical) pipeline workflow I'm looking for is this:

1. Compress assets, using hashes of content for filename
2. Stores those filenames in a cache or a module or *something* that can be *easily* referenced when it's time to render the HTML.

I shouldn't have to have every static file on all of my web front-end nodes -- only the CDN.

Right now, I feel like my best option is to hack support for caching filename hashes into `django-pipeline`, but I'm dreaming of a drop-in solution for this.

What are my best options in Django for this? Are there any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`django-pipeline` 1.1.12 is now caching hash, so you should be fine, see the [changelog](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html#id1).

**Disclaimer**: I'm one of the author of `django-pipeline`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Django 1.3? If so, then you can write your own [custom file storage backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-from-a-cloud-service-or-cdn) that uploads things to a CDN. Luckily, if you want to use Amazon S3, then [`django-storages`](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/wiki/Home) already does exactly what you want!